# Source of the Rambam's statement?

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, messianic-redemption

Where exactly does the Rambam say the following in his Igeres Teiman:

> “When the gentiles think that this people will never have their own government and state, and they will never be redeemed from their exile, and all the sages of the world say this unanimously, including the sorcerers and those who understand the powers, Hashem will annul their thoughts and their false logic, and then moshiach will be revealed. This is what Yishaya (44:25-26) said, ‘Who frustrates the signs of imposters, and diviners He makes mad; He turns the wise backwards, and makes their knowledge foolish. He fulfils the word of His servant, and the counsel of His messenger He completes; Who says of Jerusalem, “It shall be settled,” and of the cities of Judah, “They shall be built, and its ruins I will erect.”’

Comment: Where did you get this quote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Iggerot_HaRambam%2C_Iggeret_Teiman.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> שכשיחשבו העכו"ם שאומה זו לא יהיה לה לעולם ממשלה ולא יגאלו מן השיעבוד שהם בו וכל החכמים כלם פה אחד בעצה זאת וגם הקוסמים בעלי הכחות יפר הקב"ה מחשבותם וסברתם הנכחשת ואז יגלה המשיח שכן אמר ישעיהו בבאור עניין זה (ישעיה מ"ד כ"ה כ"ו) מפר אותות בדים וקוסמים יהולל משיב חכמים אחור ודעתם יסכל מקים דבר עבדו ועצת מלאכיו ישלים האומר לירושלים תושב ולערי יהודה תבנינה וחרבותיה אקומם